# Angular Ionic hybrid app HTML5 Audio Element is not playing all .wav, .mp3

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, html5-audio, capacitor

The app is recording audio messages and saving them in firebase. Whenever I fetch files from firebase storage some of the audios are not playing. iPhone records audio/mpeg, browser and android records audio/webm. I know HTML5 Audio supports only three formats. But all works in a browser. Natively even audio/mpeg is not always playing.

I'm using capacitor, ionic and natively HTML5 audio element. It's failing to play .wav, .mp3. As soon as I build native app it fails to play songs. I've tried different formats. Sometimes mp3 is working, sometimes not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/Cap-go/native-audio